# Render arbitrary polygon with XNA

Tags: xna, polygon, vertex

Looking for a simple way to render a list of arbitrary vertices (on a 2d plane) ... I'm guessing that I'll have to do some sort of tessellation, and will have to deal with concave/convex polygons. Not looking for a crazy visualization here ... just want to render a flat shape.

Surely others have encountered this need before? any tips would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually after triangulation.

Try Nick Gravelyn's [Triangulator](http://triangulator.codeplex.com/) library. Last time I used it there was a bug in that some polygons would triangulate inside-out. But if you poke around the bug tracker I think there's a fix there (perhaps [this one](http://triangulator.codeplex.com/workitem/24623)).

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I actually updated the project to XNA 4 and submitted a patch, which Nick accepted and applied. Thanks Andrew :-)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how simple you need to go, you can check out this [Primitives Sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives) on msdn. It's ripped out of the SpaceWar sample and should get you started with basic primitives.